# Is the Haversine Formula or the Vincenty's Formula better for calculating distance?

Tags: mapping-space, graph-distance

Which is better for calculating the distance between two latitude/longitude points, The Haversine Formula or The Vincenty's Formula? Why?

The distance is obviously being calculated on Earth. Does WGS84 vs GCJ02 coordinates impact the calculation or distance (The Vincenty's formula takes the WGS84 axis into consideration)?

The Haversine Formula is used in [Google Map Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils), but the Vincenty Formula is used by the android.Location object (Location.distanceBetween()).

Comment: Cross-posted on SO: [Is the Haversine Formula or the Vincenty's Formula for calculating distance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38248046).

Comment: Wasn't sure which audience would get the most traction. It's a mathematical question, but both algorithms I'm using deal with mobile software mapping.

Comment: This site is for professional mathematicians, most of them do not necessarily know what WGS84 or GCJ092 stand for, or even what "haversine" is. If you want an answer, state your question in the terms that an average mathematician can understand.

Comment: Seems like a good answer was provided @AlexandreEremenko. The best part about this website is that nobody is forcing you to partake in the question.

Comment: See my answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248046/is-the-haversine-formula-or-the-vincentys-formula-better-for-calculating-distan/38663071#38663071  This makes the (important) distinction between *what* you're trying to calculation and *how* you're calculating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) [no capital, [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine#Haversine) = "halve versed sine" is not the name of a person] calculates the distance between longitude/latitude points assuming a spherical earth. [Vincenty's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) takes into account that the earth is not perfectly spherical, by calculating the ellipsoidal distance between two points on the surface of a spheroid. [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#A_new_World_Geodetic_System:_WGS_84) refers to a model for the ellipsoidal earth, [GCJ-02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China#GCJ-02) is a (crippled) Chinese implementation of the same model. The error made by the spherical earth formula is at most 100 km, for the largest distances. Here you can find a [comparison](http://www.r-bloggers.com/great-circle-distance-calculations-in-r/) of the two formulas for a selection of points on earth.

Comment: Thanks @carlo, yea I've very familiar with GCJ-02 as I used it heavily (and BD09). I know that Vincenty's takes into account the earth is not a perfect sphere and uses WSG84. thanks for the article!